# A matrix $g$ is in the Unitary Group iff $g \bar g^t=I$

Tags: group-theory, unitary-matrices

The Unitary group was defined as follows:
$U_n = \{g \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}):<gu,gv>=<u,v> u,v\in \mathbb C^n\}$
 Where $<u,v>=\sum_1^n u_i \bar v_i$

I'm trying to prove that a matrix $g$ is in the Unitary Group iff $g\bar{g}^t=I $

My attempt (for =>) is to take specific vectors in $\mathbb C^n$. For example if I take $u_i=v_i=(0,...0,1,0,..0)$ where the $1$ is at the $i$th place I get that $g_i \bar g_i^t=1$ for all $i$ and that if $i\neq j$ than $g_i \bar g_j^t=0$. Does it follow that $g\bar{g}^t=I$ ?

I don't know where to start proving the other direction. Or is it exactly the same going backwards?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct; supposing $g \in U_n$ and letting $e_i$ be the $i^{\text{th}}$ standard basis vector, you have shown that $(g\overline g^t)_{ij} = \langle g_i, g_j\rangle = \langle ge_i, ge_j\rangle = \langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. This shows that $g\overline g^t = I$. The backwards direction is actually easier: if $g\overline g^t = I$, then $\langle gu , gv\rangle = \langle \overline g^t g u,v\rangle = \langle Iu,v\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle.$

Comment: @User8128 Thank you for your help. Can you explain the backwards directions a bit more? why does $<gu,gv>=<\bar g^t u,v>$?

Comment: @SlyxBrd This is a definition of the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map).

Answer (score 1):

Use the theorem about the existence of adjoint operator:

$$gg^t=I\implies\;\forall\,u\in \Bbb C^n\;,\;\;\langle u,\,u\rangle=\langle u,\,g^*gu\rangle=\langle gu,\,gu\rangle$$

and we're done, since in unitary linear spaces, $\;g^*=\overline g^t=\overline{g^t}\;$

The other direction: for all $\;u\in\Bbb C^n\;$ ,we have

$$\langle u,\,u\rangle=\langle gu,\,gu\rangle=\langle u,\,g^*gu\rangle\implies g^*g=I$$

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't that like using what you are trying to prove in order to prove it? And can you please explain why $<u,g^*gu>=<gu,gu>$?

Comment: @SlyxBrd That is **always** true in any linear space with an inner product and for any operator on it...!